# Plotting labled time series in pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I want to plot several time series on the same graph. On the horizontal, I want a point where the ts says something happened. The vertical axis is the label of the series. So all the A ts points are at the same y value and labeled A. The B points are at a different y value labeled B. Etc.

I'm a bit of a pandas newbie, but I'm not seeing how to do this except via a bit of programming to make a scatter plot. Which seems like I'm doing it wrong.

Here's an example.  Consider this data, which is label followed by time:

```
cows 1416339311
cats 1416339312
dogs 1416339313
dogs 1416339314
cows 1416339330
cats 1416339339
cats 1416339340
```

Then the plot would be this:

[image: something about animals over time]

A more realistic plot would be something like this, which shows us that cows are active early, cats early and late, and dogs mostly in mid-time:

[image: lots of animals over time]

Comment: can you give some example data and then maybe an example of the output you want? Do a basic plot then even hand draw on it the additional bits you would like to add. It's hard to take your question and visualize what you are after.

Comment: JD Long - good idea, done

Comment: What's the x axis? is it the time index or the value in the data?

Comment: so the data from your example is not captured in the plot? Thinking of the [1,2,3,4,4.75,5,6] from your table

Comment: ohhhh... now I'm getting it

Comment: Yes, the time data is where the poitns appear on the X axis. So imagine I'm watching some cows, cats, and dogs. At time t, an animal makes a noise. I note the type of animal and the time. And so it it goes. Now (see the second plot) we know that cows mostly make noise early in the day, the dogs mostly mid-day, and the cats both early and late. And it's that visualisation of the three time series that I'm trying to get.

Comment: Pandas makes this slightly tricky by not supporting point data. It does scatter plots, but that's not really what we have here. And you will struggle plotting categorical data (cows, cats, dogs) on an axis. I recommend facets (subplots) for plotting each species. So a short but wide chart for each species.

Comment: i think this could be visualized as a histogram for each species... x axis is hour and height is sounds per hour... or 5 minute interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the above help from JD Long, this is the function I finally wrote:

```
def plot_times_by_club(df, live, zero):
"""Plot the times for each club.

If zero is True, then set first x-tick at 0 seconds (beginning of race)."""
times = df.loc[:, ['time', 'club']]
clubs = times.club.unique()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(clubs), sharex=True, sharey=True)
for index, club in enumerate(clubs):
    these_times = times[times.club == club]
    ax[index].plot(these_times.time.as_matrix(), np.ones(len(these_times)), 'o')
    ax[index].set_ylabel(club, rotation='horizontal', labelpad=30)
    ax[index].set_yticks([])
    ax[index].set_ybound(0.5, 1.5)
    ax[index].set_position([0.1, 0.1, 8.0, 1.0])
    ax[index].set_yticks([])
ax[0].set_title('Temps vu par club')
min_tick = ax[0].get_xticks().min()
if zero:
    min_tick = 0.0
    ax[0].set_xbound(lower=0.0)
max_tick = ax[0].get_xticks().max()
ax[0].set_xticks(np.linspace(min_tick, max_tick, 6))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
render_plot(8, 6, live, 'jn8-club-{0}.png'.format(zero))

def render_plot(xdim, ydim, live, filename):
"""Display or save the plot image.

If live is True, then display in a window.
If live is False, save to the named file."""
if live:
    plt.show()
else:
    gc = plt.gcf()
    gc.set_size_inches(xdim, ydim)
    gc.savefig(filename, dpi=100)
```